# How to get required keys from multiple JSONs at once?

Tags: python, json, api, parsing

I want to get keys from several JSON objects which I receive using the requests library. There's a list of names I use for API call in a loop. This is how I try to get the values:

```
for i in name:
    media_info = requests.get(URI)
    print (media_info.text)

{"error":"no_transcoder"}

{"tracks":[{"bitrate":191,"channels":2,"codec":"mp3","content":"audio","lang":"eng","sample_rate":44100,"track_id":"a1"},{"bframes":3,"bitrate":3452,"codec":"h264","content":"video","fps":29.97,"gop_size":110,"height":1080,"lang":"eng","last_gop":72,"level":"4.0","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","pixel_height":1080,"pixel_width":1920,"profile":"High","sar_height":1,"sar_width":1,"track_id":"v1","width":1920}]}

{"provider":"FFmpeg","title":"Service01","tracks":[{"bframes":1,"bitrate":3717,"codec":"h264","content":"video","fps":59.94,"gop_size":69,"height":720,"last_gop":101,"level":"4.0","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","pixel_height":720,"pixel_width":1280,"profile":"High","sar_height":1,"sar_width":1,"track_id":"v1","width":1280},{"bitrate":192,"channels":2,"codec":"aac","content":"audio","sample_rate":48000,"track_id":"a1"}]} 

media_data = json.loads(media_info.text)
media_json = media_data['tracks'][0]['fps']
media_info_data.append(media_json)
print (media_info_data)

[59.94]
```

The problem is that I receive only the last value.

How to collect all the fps keys even if there's {"error":"no_transcoder"}?

How to get fps, gop and bitrate keys?

Comment: You're only getting the last value because the last four lines of code aren't inside the for loop.

Comment: I know. I tried somehow to push it in a loop but then I always had a crash.

Comment: When the last 4 lines are in loop I get KeyError: 'tracks' error. I know why - because it tries to find tracks in {"error":"no_transcoder"}. But how to handle such cases?

Comment: If the result json has an "error" key, then skip it.  `if "error" in media_data: continue`

Answer (score 0):

Succesfully got the required keys. Need to add try-expect code for the KeyError exception

```
for i in name:
    media_info = requests.get(URI)
    print (media_info.text)

{"error":"no_transcoder"}

{"tracks":[{"bitrate":191,"channels":2,"codec":"mp3","content":"audio","lang":"eng","sample_rate":44100,"track_id":"a1"},{"bframes":3,"bitrate":3452,"codec":"h264","content":"video","fps":29.97,"gop_size":110,"height":1080,"lang":"eng","last_gop":72,"level":"4.0","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","pixel_height":1080,"pixel_width":1920,"profile":"High","sar_height":1,"sar_width":1,"track_id":"v1","width":1920}]}

{"provider":"FFmpeg","title":"Service01","tracks":[{"bframes":1,"bitrate":3717,"codec":"h264","content":"video","fps":59.94,"gop_size":69,"height":720,"last_gop":101,"level":"4.0","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","pixel_height":720,"pixel_width":1280,"profile":"High","sar_height":1,"sar_width":1,"track_id":"v1","width":1280},{"bitrate":192,"channels":2,"codec":"aac","content":"audio","sample_rate":48000,"track_id":"a1"}]} 

    media_data = json.loads(media_info.text)
    if "error" in media_data: continue
    try:
        media_json = media_data['tracks'][0]['fps']
    except KeyError:
        media_json = media_data['tracks'][1]['fps']
    media_info_data.append(media_json)
```